# Why am I getting an error in df.transform when I should be able to execute arbitrary functions?

Tags: python, pandas

I believe that df.transform can perform arbitrary functions.
For example df.transform(lambda x: x + 10) etc.

However, a simple math.ceil() gives me an error.
This can be solved with np.ceil(), but why is there an error in df.transform, which should be able to execute arbitrary functions?

```
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'V':[1, 1.5, 2]})

df.transform(lambda x: x + 10)        #OK
df.transform(lambda x: np.ceil(x))    #OK

df.transform(lambda x: math.ceil(x))
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>  #NG. Why?
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `math.ceil` gets a float as an input, and cannot work with `pd.Series` as input, while `np.ceil` is a vectorized function that can get either float or series (array) as input.

You should refer to a specific series:

```
df.V.transform(lambda x: math.ceil(x))
```

The other works fine since they are vectorized functions and can work on a `pd.Series`

Comment: Thanks David, I was actually thinking of a more complex function, but I will give it a try.

Comment: @KennyISHIMURA If you want to share this I will be happy to assist :)